# What WKT type does Parliament Want?

Tags: sparql, geosparql, parliament

I'm getting the following error message from Parliament 2.7.9 which did not occur for the same data under Parliament 2.7.4:

```
2016-10-06 14:39:53,362 [qtp766572210-18] WARN  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.index.spatial.geosparql.datatypes.WKTLiteral] Accepting WKT geometry with incorrect datatype sf:wktLiteral
```

This appears to be in reference to triples loaded into Parliament such as:

```
http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/PoCDemo/DemoInstantiations#GEO_Philippines-RequestAOIs-143500N1205800E_R200_AOI http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT   "<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84> POLYGON((120.57999999999993 16.146640990673784, 120.70936350638135 16.142264463519364, 120.8380967667631 16.12915620405647, 120.96557260564123 16.10738007440757, 121.09116997354204 16.077042165687384, 121.21427697271452 16.038290281137638, 121.33429383823318 15.991313216044539, 121.45063585999344 15.936339837947095, 121.56273623135974 15.873637971617498, 121.67004881059108 15.803513094245734, 121.77205078158863 15.726306847185427, 121.86824520100276 15.642395371511515, 121.95816341929162 15.552187475498728, 122.04136736393411 15.456122642948774, 122.11745167367576 15.354668892069432, 122.1860456734073 15.248320495336891, 122.24681518005718 15.13759557144993, 122.2994641306974 15.023033561107695, 122.34373602493292 14.90519259890884, 122.37941517454499 14.784646794175867, 122.40632775430322 14.66198343395221, 122.42434264882445 14.537800121798805, 122.43337209135325 14.412701866329597, 122.43337209135325 14.287298133670403, 122.42434264882445 14.162199878201195, 122.40632775430322 14.038016566047789, 122.37941517454499 13.915353205824132, 122.34373602493292 13.794807401091159, 122.2994641306974 13.676966438892304, 122.24681518005718 13.56240442855007, 122.1860456734073 13.451679504663108, 122.11745167367576 13.345331107930567, 122.04136736393411 13.243877357051225, 121.95816341929162 13.147812524501271, 121.86824520100276 13.057604628488484, 121.77205078158863 12.973693152814572, 121.67004881059108 12.896486905754267, 121.56273623135974 12.826362028382501, 121.45063585999344 12.763660162052904, 121.33429383823318 12.708686783955462, 121.21427697271452 12.66170971886236, 121.09116997354204 12.622957834312617, 120.96557260564123 12.59261992559243, 120.8380967667631 12.57084379594353, 120.70936350638135 12.557735536480637, 120.57999999999993 12.553359009326215, 120.4506364936185 12.557735536480637, 120.32190323323675 12.57084379594353, 120.19442739435863 12.59261992559243, 120.06883002645782 12.622957834312617, 119.94572302728534 12.66170971886236, 119.82570616176667 12.70868678395546, 119.70936414000641 12.763660162052904, 119.59726376864012 12.826362028382501, 119.48995118940877 12.896486905754266, 119.38794921841122 12.973693152814572, 119.29175479899709 13.057604628488484, 119.20183658070823 13.147812524501271, 119.11863263606574 13.243877357051225, 119.0425483263241 13.345331107930566, 118.97395432659255 13.451679504663106, 118.91318481994267 13.562404428550067, 118.86053586930245 13.676966438892304, 118.81626397506693 13.794807401091159, 118.78058482545487 13.915353205824132, 118.75367224569663 14.038016566047789, 118.7356573511754 14.162199878201195, 118.7266279086466 14.2872981336704, 118.7266279086466 14.412701866329598, 118.7356573511754 14.537800121798805, 118.75367224569663 14.66198343395221, 118.78058482545487 14.784646794175867, 118.81626397506693 14.90519259890884, 118.86053586930245 15.023033561107695, 118.91318481994267 15.13759557144993, 118.97395432659255 15.248320495336891, 119.0425483263241 15.354668892069432, 119.11863263606574 15.456122642948774, 119.20183658070823 15.552187475498728, 119.29175479899709 15.642395371511515, 119.38794921841122 15.726306847185427, 119.48995118940877 15.803513094245732, 119.59726376864012 15.873637971617496, 119.70936414000641 15.936339837947095, 119.82570616176667 15.991313216044539, 119.94572302728534 16.038290281137638, 120.06883002645782 16.077042165687384, 120.19442739435863 16.10738007440757, 120.32190323323675 16.12915620405647, 120.4506364936185 16.142264463519364, 120.57999999999993 16.146640990673784))"^^http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral
```

In short, Parliament does not like the predicate http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT with a literal object of type http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral.  So, my question is, **what is the proper type for this literal to make Parliament 2.7.9 happy?**

Ignoring these warnings is not an option for me because with my dataset there are so many of them that they slow down processing unacceptably.

Comment: It may be the use of the placeholder URI http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84 for an unspecified CRS that's the issue, rather than the predicate.

Comment: Thank you @chrisis.  The polygon coordinates are decimal latitude and longitude (in this example case, a polygon representing a 200km radius circle entered about Manila, Philippines if memory serves).  Do you know of the appropriate URI for the decimal latitude/longitude Coordinate Reference System?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, No real GIS knowledge, just picked up this while doing some work a while ago.